# Coalesce columns in pyspark and replace values?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have 2 dataframes each with 1 column of boolean data. I am more interested if a row is true than if it's false, so I am trying to coalesce the 2 columns together, replacing false values in one dataframe if the same row is true in the other dataframe.

For example my 2 dataframes are like this:

```
label1

false
false
false
true
true
```

```
label2

true
false
false
false
true
```

Expected output coalescing label1 and label2 and prioritising true values:

```
label

true
false
false
true
true
```

Is there a way to do this in pyspark? I have looked into using `coalesce(df['label1'],df['label2'])` but I don't know how to specify that I want true values to always be kept

Comment: How would you combine the two dataframes before using `coalesce`? In general Spark dataframes do not have an order so you would need a common join column in both dataframes.

Comment: I could give them both a ```row_num``` column of IDs if that would then work? They are both the same length being initially made from the same dataframe from which I coded 2 if else conditions to create the 2 columns. I'm new to pyspark so not sure what's best for me to do

Comment: If possible, you should keep them both in the same dataframe. Just add the two new boolean columns to the original dataframe.